# Absolute most basic T-SQL DELETE statement causing a timeout

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql

This is going to top some of the weirdest things I've seen. I've tried looking up "simple t-sql delete causing timeout" but all titles are misleading, they say simple but are not. They deal with deleting millions of records or have complex relationships setup. I do not.

I have four tables:

tblInterchangeControl,
tblFunctionalGroup,
tblTransactionSet,
tblSegment

The latter 3 all associate to tblInterchangeConrol via InterchangeControlID. There are no relationships setup. like I said as simple as one could get.

The procedure runs a delete statement on all 4 tables like so...

```
DELETE FROM tblSegment 
WHERE (ID_InterchangeControlID = @InterchangeControlID)

DELETE FROM tblTransactionSet 
WHERE (ID_InterchangeControlID = @InterchangeControlID)

DELETE FROM tblFunctionalGroup 
WHERE (ID_InterchangeControlID = @InterchangeControlID)

DELETE FROM tblInterchangeControl 
WHERE (InterchangeControlID = @InterchangeControlID)
```

The weird part is if I leave these in the procedure it times out, if I remove them, it does not. I've pinned it to these delete statements that are the cause. But Why?!

I included c# because I'm calling this procedure from a c# application. I don't think this is the issue but maybe. I only say I don't think so because my code work just fine when I remove the delete statements inside the stored procedure. Then if I put them back, an exception is thrown that it's timed out.

Comment: Most likely you have some locks holding that up.

Comment: Snap I think you're right.. I haven't necessarily encountered lock problems before. This is all happening in a loop that is creating the records I'm also trying to delete, the insert is in a transaction, the delete is not. I think I'm going to have to do a bit of reworking to get this to work. I'll report back as soon as I make some progress or have more information.

Comment: Why do you not have any relationships established? Seems to me like this would be a good place to have foreign keys with cascading deletes? As a side note your naming conventions appear to be a bit odd to me. Why ID_InterchangeControlID? And why the tbl prefixes on all your tables?

Comment: @SeanLange I don't want to set them up yet, the project and business logic are taking precedence. I don't disagree with you though. This would be a prime place to setup relationships. The naming convention also may seem odd, but it's also taken out of context. ID_ indicates it's a foreign key. Also tbl is just prefixed to any object that is a table, and this applies to our internal projects across the board i.e. ms access, oracle, mysql, t-sql. It comes in hand when the objects are not sorted in a tree view.

Comment: I figured both of those naming conventions. The table prefix is known is "tbling" (pronounced tibling) and is one of things that some shops insist on that is truly just silly.

Comment: As for not yet having relationships in your data...how can you build an application with data that doesn't yet have the actual data structure with RI enforced???

Comment: Yeah I rather see consistency over anything, I may not always agree with some internal conversions but normally I have no other choice. But as for the references. I chose not to because I've ensured integrity is maintained by the application. It can be done, perhaps I chose a more difficult and stubborn route, but scalability is on my side.

Answer (score 2):

In case my comment is the answer.
Most likely you have some locks holding those deletes up.

Comment: Thank you, I was just going to add that and give you credit. A transaction that inserted the records was locking the separated delete from deleting those same records.

Comment: @DavidCarrigan You can click the check to accept the answer

Answer (score 1):

If you run a query from a command line SQL tool or from SQL Management Studio it will take whatever it needs to complete the query. So yes, most likely it's client part issue. And, because you mentioned c# it's probably [ADO.NET command timeout](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtimeout%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Also, I'd suggest to profile the queries by inspecting their execution plans. In case you don't have indexes (primary/unique key constraints) this will result to full-scan, i.e. O(n) operation you don't want.

**Update:**
OK, looks like it's ADO.NET error. In your code, just prior executing the command increase the timeout:

```
var myCommand = new SqlCommand("EXEC ..."); // you create it something like this
....
myCommand.CommandTimeout = 300; // 5 minutes
myCommand.ExecuteNonReader(); // assuming your SP doesn't return anything
```

Comment: This is the exception I receive (it's also taking a minute, not the default 30 seconds for a command timeout): Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding. The statement has been terminated. The inner exception is: The wait operation timed out

Comment: Where is the SQL server you're accessing ? On your local machine ?

Comment: Yes. But I do now believe it was a locking issue. I forgot where I tried to stick this delete statement. It just so happened to be where the insert was occurring apart of a transaction. The delete was not. I added the delete statement to the transaction and viola! it worked.